# Beamer and biblatex : changing the color of the journal or publisher

Tags: beamer, biblatex, color

I am using Beamer with biblatex.

When I use the code below, it produces the following slide.

I would like to change the color of the journal and the publisher (if it is only possible to have the same color, it is fine for me).  Is it possible?

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First category
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=FC, heading=none,keyword=fstcat]
\item Second category
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=SC, heading=none,keyword=sndcat]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The .bib file

```
@article {test1,
AUTHOR = {LastName1, FirstName1},
TITLE = {A long title that says nothing interesting},
JOURNAL = {Big journal},
VOLUME = {1},
YEAR = {1111},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {1--111},
keywords={fstcat}
 }

@book {test2,
AUTHOR = {LastName2, FirstName2},
TITLE = {A long title that says nothing interesting again},
PUBLISHER = {Big publisher},
YEAR = {1111},
keywords={sndcat}
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the field format of biblatex for that?

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage{xcolor} ` with beamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=red}
```